Apex Client-side Condition
I have a Client-side Condition which looks like this:

And I would like to have the value come from a sql query instead of a static value.
The query would be something like this:
select distinct UNIT_ID from CAS.AREA
where LOCATION_ID = :P3_Location and TYPE = 'CUSTOMS'
;

Thanks for any help

A client condition is exactly what it says: a condition of something that is available on the client, in the DOM of the current page. If the condition depends on the results of a SQL query that is executed at that moment, it's not possible to do this as a client condition.
The workaround is:

Create an extra page item that will serve as source for your client condition, say P3_CLIENT_CONDITION
Create a true action to run before the action you want to the client condition to fire on of type execute server-side code to set P3_CLIENT_CONDITION (to Y or N). Make sure to also put this page item in "Items to return" and to put P3_CMU_SERIAL in "Items to Submit". In the code check if the item value is in the list.
In the actual action you need the client condition on, set client condition item = value to P3_CLIENT_CONDITION = Y

